# Saving DLL file resources to a database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dll, binaryfiles

what is the advantage and disadvantage in saving the resource dll into the database. is the code in it wont change or corrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single character is replaced or altered your dll will not work.

Comment: thanks for the answer.,but when the decryption of that is correct..does it meant that the dll will also work?